# Javascript function calling members of parameter objects

Tags: javascript

Javascript:

```
var myfunc = function(foo, bar) {
  foo.thing();
  bar.stuff();
  };
```

if `foo` and `bar` will always be objects with functions `thing` and `stuff`, but `foo` and `bar` have not been declared as global variables because they could be any of a number of objects meeting this criteria, what is the proper way to declare `myfunc`?

And what if `myfunc` is a member of another object?

**EDIT**
Less generic case (node.js/express):

```
var express = require("express");
app = express();
app.set("views", __dirname + "html");

var myfunc = function(req, res) {
  res.render("file.html");
  };

app.get("/", function(req, res) {
  myfunc(req, res);
  });
// ^ OR v    Tried both, but it doesn't get this far
app.get("/", myfunc(req, res));

app.listen(8080);
```

Errors state in `var myfunc = function(req, res) {` that `res.render()` is undefined.

Comment: Identifiers in the formal parameter list become local to the function as if they were declared, so there are no issues with undeclared variables. There will be issues if you don't pass callable objects as the first and second parameters though.

Comment: I don't understand the goal of this question. :D Do you need validation by the arguments or what?

Comment: are you asking about how to do actual function invocation??

Comment: JavaScript is dynamically typed. You can't enforce the types of the variables just with the declaration. You will have to validate the parameters.

Comment: With your node.js code, you would use `app.get("/", myfunc);` and `app.get` will invoke your function with the 2 parameters.

Comment: You are looking for `app.get("/", myfunc);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT: Specific Case**

Change `app.get("/", myfunc(req, res));` to `app.get("/", myfunc);`.
This will run the function correctly.

Also, I believe `app.set("views", __dirname + "html");` should be `app.set("views", __dirname + "/html");` if the folder `html` exists inside the current directory.

## Full Answer

### JavaScript is Dynamically Typed

What you have there is perfectly fine.  It is not necessary to have the `foo` and `bar` objects declared when you declare the `myfunc()` function.

However, you will have some issues if someone passes objects to `myfunc` that don't have the `thing` and `stuff` methods.  So in order to avoid errors, there are a couple ways you can check.

### Validate Methods

The first is to see if the objects have the proper methods:

```
var myfunc = function(foo, bar) {
    if (typeof foo.thing === 'function')
        foo.thing();
    if (typeof bar.stuff === 'function')
        bar.stuff();
};
```

### Validate Object Instsance

You can also make sure that the objects are instances of the required class:

```
var Qux = function() {
    return {
        thing: function() {
            console.log('I am a thing!');
        },
        stuff: function() {
            console.log('Yikes! That\'s a bunch of stuff');
        }
    };
};

var foo = new Qux();
var bar = new Qux();

var myfunc = function(foo, bar) {
    if (foo instanceof Qux)
        foo.thing();
    if (bar instanceof Qux)
        bar.stuff();
};

myfunc(foo,bar);
```

Comment: I made the initial example generic to be flexible, but removing the () in my specific instance fixed it. Also the /html was just a typo moving it into the question, my original code has the /. I will update the question to fix that.

Comment: Be careful with *typeof* tests. In less modern browsers, many of which are still in use, callable (host or exotic) objects may not return "function" and may return all sorts of values such as "unknown" or "object". There are also standard exotic and non–standard exotic objects.

Answer (score 0):

What you have would be considered correct. You will just need to be careful to pass in objects that abide by the contract of `myfunc`. By that I mean you must be sure that the objects you pass in contain the functions `thing()` and `stuff()`, respectively.

Variables declared as parameters are local to that function. You don't need to worry about a global `foo` or `bar` interfering with `myfunc`. But, you must also realize if you *do* have those global variables defined they won't be used unless you explicitly pass them in.

Answer (score 0):

if you are asking about the actual function invocation you could simply do:

`myfunc('obj1',obj2)`.

If `myfunc` is a property under another object, say `obj3`, then:

`obj3.myfunc('obj1',obj2)`.

**EDIT:**

After the edit in OP.. the above ans is no longer relevant

You should be simply doing
`app.get("/",  myfunc);`

Answer (score 0):

The objects get redeclared as independent variables once inside, I would recommend reading you don't know JS here for a good primer on how the function gets declared and what happens implicitly to these objects:

https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/scope%20%26%20closures/ch1.md

You still need to make some checks to make sure the objects you pass can be invoked, for that the top answer has a great method.

As far as it being part of another object there would be no problems outside of using *this*.